# Is it possible to display an AlertDialog with animation starting from the position where the screen is tapped?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

Is it possible to display an `AlertDialog`, similar to `Container transform` in the [animations](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) package, starting from the position where the screen is tapped? In this case, the container is not initially displayed, and it should be triggered by receiving `onTap` with a `GestureDetector` from an empty area. Then, I want to show the animated dialog as described above.

Answer (score 4):

I guest ,Flutter's animations package did not have a built-in Container Transform like the one in Material Motion. However, you can create a custom animated dialog that starts from the position where the screen is tapped.

To achieve this, you can follow these general steps:

1. Wrap your main content with a `GestureDetector` to detect taps on an empty area.
2. Upon detecting a tap, record the tap's position (i.e., the `Offset`).
3. Show a hidden or empty container at that recorded position and use an animation (e.g., `AnimatedContainer`) to reveal the content of the dialog with a desired animation.
4. You can use an animation library like `animations` or Flutter's built-in `AnimationController` and `AnimationBuilder` to control the animations.

Here's a simplified example of how you can do this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedDialogExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedDialogExampleState createState() => _AnimatedDialogExampleState();
}

class _AnimatedDialogExampleState extends State<AnimatedDialogExample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Offset _tapPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onTap(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
    });
    _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (details) => _onTap(context, details),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Animated Dialog Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Tap on an empty area to trigger the dialog.'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: _buildAnimatedDialog(),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAnimatedDialog() {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        final animationValue = _animationController.value;
        final dialogOpacity = Curves.easeInOut.transform(animationValue);
        final dialogScale = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
            .transform(animationValue);

        final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        final dialogSize = 200.0; // Adjust this size as per your requirement

        return Positioned(
          top: _tapPosition.dy - (dialogSize / 2) + (dialogSize / 2) * dialogScale,
          left: _tapPosition.dx - (dialogSize / 2) + (dialogSize / 2) * dialogScale,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: dialogOpacity,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: dialogScale,
              child: Container(
                width: dialogSize,
                height: dialogSize,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Your Dialog Content'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: AnimatedDialogExample(),
  ));
}
```

In this example, the `_onTap` method is triggered when the user taps on an empty area. The `_tapPosition` stores the position of the tap, and then the `_animationController` is used to animate the dialog's opacity and scale. The dialog will appear and grow from the tap position, creating the effect of the dialog being triggered by the tap gesture.